# What is "processing time" in chrome developer tools performance insights?

Tags: google-chrome, http, web, web-performance

I am trying to analyze performance of a web-app. Our web-app issues many requests in parallel, and when I analyze the network via "performance insights" in chrome developer tools, [I am seeing this chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bD0N0.png)

I noticed several facts:

- The "processing time" is the largest portion of the request handling time. I chose a page with a relatively large amount of parallel requests. In other page, the portion of "processing time" is smaller (for the same requests).
- This time is not shown in the network tab of the chrome developer tools. Over that tab, i can only see "request sent", "waiting" and "download"
- On the left side, the processing time is denoted by the thin line.
- All the thin lines end almost exactly at the same exact millisecond.

I could not find any explanation about the processing time in the google documentation for "performance insights".  I suspect there's some sort of response queueing happening inside chrome.

Can someone explain what is the meaning of the processing time, and why am I seeing this behavior?